# Can I use sentence "All rights reserved" on my web page/site or blog with out registering at gov copyright office

Tags: blog, copyright, registration

I have a query, people are saying that since 1989, every work which is created is automatically copyrighted. Then is it fine to use sentence 
**All rights reserver** and copy right symbol on my website, with out registering at gov copyright office.

Comment: Although not an exact dupe, the canonical question above answers this question well.

Comment: For what it is worth, *all rights reserved* is a legal statement that means *all rights reserved*. It has nothing to do with copyright, trademarks, or anything else specifically. It is a general legal notice meaning that you have not given any rights away with the offering you have made publicly or otherwise.